# net disconnect screen in react native

Tags: react-native

When I am on login page, if net disconnect then it must navigate to no net screen only on login page, not on whole mobile app.

```
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  "connectionChange",
  this.handleConnectivityChange
);

componentWillUnmount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
    "connectionChange",
    this.handleConnectivityChange
  );
}

handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
  if (isConnected) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(SCREENS.LOGIN);
  } else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(SCREENS.NO_INTERNET_MESSAGE);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to internet connection only in your login component not in every component in your app and not in your App class.

In your login component :

```
handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
  if (isConnected) {
    // just write your login process
  } else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(SCREENS.NO_INTERNET_MESSAGE);
  }
};
```

otherwise , every time there's no internet, every component will be redirected to your login page and automatically to no_internet screen.